# How to set Git staging directory?

Tags: git, location, staging

Window 7, Git

I am learning Git.  What are the commands to see and set the location of the staging directory.  I have long made it a point to never keep any personal data on the C drive (System drive) and want to pick the location of the staging directory.

Edit:  I see the comments about creating the repository.  But my understanding is that Git is a three stage process.

1. edit the code.
2. Stage it (local commit)
3. Commit it to the repository, presuming the repository is elsewhere.

After creating a repository and executing:  git config --list   There is nothing that shows the location of the repository or the staging area.

I presume that staging area is different from the repository.  Is it significantly different or just another repository with a different designated use?

Edit again:  While continuing to read Pro Git, there are a few items I am not detecting.

I would like to see a few statements that explicitly state how to create or declare:  the work area, the staging area, and the repository.

I would like these instructions to state if the current directory for the command line operation should be in that directory or should the location be presented as an argument.

I have not used Unix/Linux for a while and am out of practice for command line operators.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the location of git repository by running

```
git init
```

command in any folder where you want to create a new repository for your file.

About files on Drive C:
as far as I know git for windows is only create personal file on disk C: only in 2 places

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\.gitconfig
```

file and

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\.ssh\
```

folder

You could use symbolic link to move it to another drive 
(you can use that [tool](https://code.google.com/p/symlinker/) to create symlinks more easily
I highly recommend you to read this book 
[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) it is easy to read and have all need information about git

EDIT:
I think I see what you mean by "the local commit" is a commit that not yet pushed into remote repository
so you need this 
git status will show what changes is made and what changes are ready to commit 
then 
you need

```
git add .
```

to stage all file(s) changes that to made (only that changes will be ready to commit)
then

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

now all changes is committed to local repo (please read this for more detail please look Pro Git [Recording Changes to the Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)

you need

```
git push
```

(or more specific)

```
git push origin/master
```

to push into your remote repo (repo url should be setup already please look Pro Git [Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes))

A picture to illustrate steps:

[image: A picture to illustrate git steps]

Here I created a new repo on my local machine and by default as you can see you don't have a remote repo setup (if you clone this repo from github or bitbucket you have it).

So you need to setup remote repo url it depends on your git server it can be github butbucket, etc 
for bitbucket:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:yourlogin/gitrepo.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

for github you can do similar (put your repo url)

*adding some summary about changes:*

Only **changes*** that was added by `git add` command will be a part of next commit (you tell git by `git add` command that it is ready to commit). After commit file(s) become a part of repo and could be pushed to remote repository on server

****changes*** - could can be new file(s), deleted file(s) or modification(s) of the existing file(s)

Comment: A.V. answered this such that it best provided what I needed.  I have Pro Git and so far it did not really address that point.  Now I am getting more out of Pro Git than before.  Thank you.   EDIT: I am new to stackoverflow.  It seems that we cannot put <cr> into a post.  How does one log off?

Comment: you need to add empty lines between paragraphs

Comment: How do I get an empty line in a comment.  When I press the enter key it exits and saves.

Comment: What is the difference between a staging directory and a repository directory.  I see    **git init** but not    **git init --repository** or   **git init --stage**

Comment: there is no staging directory in git you have stage files (`git add <files>`) that is ready to commit in repository and you can **push** (`git push`) your repository changes to remote repository

Comment: I added picture to explain steps better and also add commands for setup your remote repository url

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation to chat.  Recognizing that, I rephrase for confirmation:  The staging of a file is a concept rather than movement or creation of data. Here is my understanding:  Start with a file.  Add it and Git becomes aware of it.  Edit it, and it becomes modified.  Tell Git it is ready to commit and it is declared staged.  Commit the file and it is copied to the repository.  Am I getting close.

Comment: yes, only **changes** (_changes_ - could can be new file(s), deleted file(s) or modification(s) of the existing file(s)) that was added by `git add command will be a part of next commit (you tell git by `git add` command that it is ready to commit). After commit file(s) become a part of repo and could be pushed to remote repository on server

Comment: You are welcome, if you like the answer, please feel free to up vote or/and mark it as right answer.

Comment: Clicking on vote up solicits the message that I should have 15 reputations.  I will vote when I can.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your local git repository is self-contained, so you're free to move it wherever you want.

Just move top-level directory (the one that contains the `.git` directory) to another drive, or [create a symbolic link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) to this directory from wherever you want it to be.

I've written [a blog post with some more details on how I do this for my pet projects](http://irleif.com/blog/2013/combining-git-and-dropbox/).